# Is the stack of a forked process shared with its parent?

Tags: linux, process, virtual-memory, fork, copy-on-write

Is the stack of a forked process shared with its parent?

If so, does this happen via shared copy-on-write pages?

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21220399/13998163) might be the answer you need.

Comment: @Roi That does not answer whether the stack is really copied or only shared via copy-on-write pages. The linked “duplicate” question is also about the heap, which I already knew was using the copy-on-write mechanism.

Comment: Virtually not, practically it is CoW-ed on a deeper level (copy-on-write). So the process can see everything as if it would be a fully copied stack. But in practice, no copy happens, only the changed pages will be copied on need.